# Using FunctionX#curried

Tags: scala

I define `foo`:

```
scala> def foo(x: Int, y:Int): Int = x + y
foo: (x: Int, y: Int)Int
```

Then I failed to set `bar` equal to the `curried` function of `foo`.

```
scala> def bar = foo.curried
<console>:8: error: missing arguments for method foo;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied 
function
       def bar = foo.curried
             ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo` is not a function, it's a method. It's not an object, it has no own methods. `curried` is a method on object of type `FunctionN`.

You have to convert it to function:

```
(foo _).curried
```

With `foo _` you are creating a new object of type `Function2`.