# _ Must Follow [Curried] Method

Tags: scala

I'm working on `map3` from [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/):

```
 // Exercise 3: The apply method is useful for implementing map3, map4, and so on
  // and the pattern is straightforward. Implement map3 and map4 using only
  // unit, apply, and the curried available on functions.
  def map3[A,B,C,D](fa: F[A],
                    fb: F[B],
                    fc: F[C])(f: (A, B, C) => D): F[D] = {
    def foo: (A => B => C => D) = (f _).curried    // compile-time error
    def fooF: F[A => B => C => D] = unit(foo)   
    val x: F[B => C => D] = apply(fooF)(fa)
    val y: F[C => D] = apply(x)(fb)
    val z: F[D] = apply(y)(fc)
    z
  }
```

One(1) compile-time error occurs on the above, noted line:

```
[error] C:\...\Applicative.scala: _ must follow method; cannot follow f.type
[error]     def foo: (A => B => C => D) = (f _).curried
[error]  

                              ^
```

I was able to successfully get the `curried` version of a function via this post - [Using FunctionX#curried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941618/using-functionxcurried).

However, I don't understand the above compile-time error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is because `f` here is a function, not a method; the `f _` syntax is to turn methods into functions, which isn't necessary here. Simply write `def foo: A => B => C => D = f.curried`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked (can't accept yet), @Huw. What does `f _` do if `f` is a method?

Comment: It turns it into the corresponding function, see §6.7 in the spec. It will also turn thunks into nullary functions: `def foo[A](v: => A): () => A = v _`

Comment: thanks. As an aside, do you (or anyone out there) have any comments on my implementation of `map3`? Criticism appreciated.